# Any good Finance API?

Tags: api, google-api, yql, stockquotes

Yahoo! Finance feeds are pain in the ass.

Google Finance API seems OK but don't know why I can't retrieve stock quotes information for Dow Johnes, NASDAQ, S&P...

Works perfect with company quotes like YHOO, MSFT but don't gets full data for stock indexes.

There is an [article](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2009/06/02/getting-stock-information-with-yql-and-open-data-tables/) at YQL blog on how to get this data from Open tables with YQL, but that table is missing in the list.

Can anybody recommend any good API, web service or a feed?

Best answer + vote up guaranteed.

Comment: So what exactly are your requirements?  What do you mean by "full data"?

Comment: Volume, change and percent (percent can be calculated if last change data is available) like Dow Johnes or NASDAQ here: http://www.google.com/finance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yahoo provides a free API via http. You can get real-time informations & historical data in csv format.

For example to get the S&P historical data (^GSPC):
[http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC&ignore=.csv](http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EGSPC&ignore=.csv)

or Dow Jones (^DJI):
[http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^DJI&ignore=.csv](http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5EDJI&ignore=.csv)

URL syntax explained at:
http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm

Comment: Thanks, seems I cant avoid Yahoo! Finance feeds...

Comment: The link to gummy-stuff.org now only contains a letter from Yahoo, arguing that the page provides tools for "hacking" Yahoo finance, and has to be removed. Which it has, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use YahooAPIs and send a YQL query that returns an XML document, such as:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22GLD,SLV%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

To make things easier, I wrote a simple [YahooFinanceAPI](https://github.com/josephdpurcell/YahooFinanceAPI) script on GitHub. Example usage:

```
$y = new YahooFinanceAPI;
$y->api(array('SLV','GLD'));
```

For more complete information you can view an article I wrote at http://thesimplesynthesis.com/article/finance-apis/.

Answer (score 2):

[Nordnet External API](https://api.test.nordnet.se/projects/api/wiki) looks good:

- Nice documentation although more sample/boilerplate code would be good.
- Support forum with some activity.
- Development environment where you can play around.

Before you can use your application for actual trades there is a certification process to ensure that your code works. 
The API is for building trading bots and not for downloading price histories though.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're using the wrong symbols for the averages?  For example, the symbol for the Dow Jones Industrial Average is [.DJI](http://www.google.com/finance?q=.DJI) - something that caused me a bit of confusion when I was searching for it.  The symbol for the S&P 500 is [.INX](http://www.google.com/finance?q=.INX), which is even more counterintuitive.

Comment: NO, it can't be... Already tried loads of variations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Interactive Brokers API. Among many other features, it has delayed and real time quotes available via the API.

http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=programInterface

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.mergent.com/servius (no stock quotes, but lots of other financial information like dividends, corporate actions and financial statements)

Answer (score -2):

@Brian: The delayed quotes are NOT available through the IB API at the time of writing. Only the real time quotes - and those are not free.

See http://ibkb.interactivebrokers.com/taxonomy/term/147

Comment: Did you want to add a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Yes, but there was no button. Sorry about that.

Comment: Right you are. You need at least 50 reputation to be able to add comments. See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment .